# C#: Get double entries in string list

Tags: c#, string, list

In C# I have a list of type string. This list contains strings with the length of 8. Now I need to find entries, where the characters from position 4 to 7 are the same and fill a second list with those entries. How would I do that?

Example content of existing list:

*tmr523fw*

*tmr5287g*

*tmx523fu*

*tmy4741g*

The new list should now contain those entries:

*tmr523fw*

*tmx523fu*

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: The usual sortings and filtering examples I found so far all related to the complete string, not parts of it. So I have no idea how I should do it :(

Comment: Please provide what exactly you´ve tried and where you´ve stuck. Currently this is just an "do this for me"-assignement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linq `GroupBy` and `Substring` should do the job here

```
List<string> items = new List<string>() { "tmr523fw", "tmr5287g", "tmx523fu", "tmy4741g" };
List<string> result = items.GroupBy(x => x.Substring(3, 4))
                           .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                           .SelectMany(x => x)
                           .ToList();
```

assuming that  double entries means the appearance `x.Count() > 1`